# does azureml sdk support c sharp language?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I want to integrate azureml-sdk into some web-page.

But currently I can only find azureml-sdk-for-python.

Is there any release for azureml-sdk-for-dotnet/c-sharp?

Just like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/ml/?view=azure-ml-py

Answer (score 1):

There are only 3 ways to use AzureML:

1. az ml cli
2. Python SDK
3. Microsoft's REST APIs

While working in Dotnet Core, the easiest way is to use the REST APIs, as then you don't need to rely on any package. Also, I believe that the python SDK is using these REST APIs in background. However, the REST APIs don't have the best documentation and its hard to find API params for some specific resources.

Another way would be to use `Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK` package and then run the `az ml cli` commands.

Lastly, you can use `IronPython` package (or something similar) to run the python sdk as well.

You can find documentation for each of the 3 methods [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/). (Check the "Reference" card on the page)

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a .NET application and want to integrate ML, use [ML.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-does-mldotnet-work).

You could find the differences in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/data-guide/technology-choices/data-science-and-machine-learning).

[image]
[image]

Comment: No, I want to use c sharp to control 'azure-ml' not ml.net.